# last updated date using oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

currently I have a process that executes every 2 hours based on updates every 2 hours on a oracle 11g table.

```
update_date >= sysdate -2/24
```

Is there anyway I can run my job every 2 hours and capture updates since the last updated run.

Thanks

Comment: You need to schedule a job and stash the maximum update date somewhere each time you run the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example how you could do that:

1) set up the data structures and initialize the job's state

```
CREATE TABLE ak_job_state(last_date DATE);
INSERT INTO ak_job_state VALUES (SYSDATE-2/24);

CREATE TABLE ak_example(c_name VARCHAR2(100), last_updated DATE);
```

2) Set up the procedure for JOB:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_for_updated IS
  v_last_date DATE;
  v_new_date  DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT last_date INTO v_last_date FROM ak_job_state FOR UPDATE NOWAIT; --get the date from storage (meanwhile serialize the access)

  v_new_date := SYSDATE; --make new date state

  FOR x IN (SELECT * FROM ak_example WHERE last_updated > v_last_date) LOOP

    --Do your stuff;
    NULL;
  END LOOP;

  UPDATE ak_job_state SET last_date = v_new_date; --Save the state
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

3) And schedule the JOB, more details on scheduler in Oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm

```
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name        => 'check_for_updated_job'
                           ,job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
                           ,job_action      => 'BEGIN check_for_updated; END;'
                           ,start_date      => SYSDATE
                           ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=2'
                           ,enabled         => TRUE
                           ,comments        => 'Update every 2 hours');
END;
/
```